# Defining img tag without height and width

Tags: xhtml

The w3c specification says that the width and height are implied and not required. I have always been told that you're supposed to put it in anyway. If I remember correctly his reason was that the browser may not correctly detect the image size. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It harkens back to the dark days of Netscape in the v4 and older versions. The rendering engines were primitive and wouldn't "reflow" content as they built pages and figured out sizes. If you didn't specify an image size, the whole page's rendering would get paused (or a full-page refresh would get pulled) once the image was downloaded and parsed for height/width. This looked bad from a user perspective, so the rule was to ALWAYS specify a size.

Nowadays, engines are better, and can handle an unspecified image size gracefully. Reflowing content is still a somewhat expensive operation, but does look cool from a user perspective as things glide/flow around as images pop in and text shifts to accomodate them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if you do not put them in, the browser will put a default size in, download the image, find the actual size then have to re-flow everything around the new size.

Re-flows are expensive operations - the rendering on screen has to be updated for each such image.

If you provide the size, the browser puts in a placeholder with the correct size and doesn't have to re-flow once the image downloads.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, not supplying width and height tags will cause the browser to render the image at its original size.

I've found this behaviour to be consistent in modern browsers.

As an aside, I always try to supply images at the size I want them rendered at in order to reduce the amount of bandwidth used and to ensure image quality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about browsers not detecting it correctly, I've never seen that happen.

But to answer your question, I think the answer depends more on what you are trying to do, and possibly likely to do, which makes the difference.

For example, if the image you are adding is a banner ad which needs to conform to predetermined height/width, then by all means, hard code the height and width.

But if the image is something that might change over time, I would suggest NOT coding the height and width, as more than likely this means that the new image, if not the same exact height/width as the old one, will now be distorted. This is especially true on a dynamic website where images change all the time.